# serialize & before_save in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `DocumentType` model w/ a `extensions` attribute. In my form I'm allowing people to insert those extensions into the form.

I want to be able to parse that input before saving, stripping out any invalid options, convert it into an array and have Rails serialize it.

I have the following code but I just end up w/ the input that the user gave in the form instead of an array:

```
class DocumentType < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :extensions

  before_save :process_extensions

  def process_extensions
    self.extensions = [*self.extensions.gsub(/[^a-z ]+/i, '').split(' ')].uniq
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried having a psuedo-property for the string input that sets the array rather than combining both into a single property?

Comment: I have not. I wanted to avoid this if possible, or at the very least understand why I'm not getting the results I expect.

Comment: Tested your code using Ruby 1.9.3p392, Rails 4.0.0, with Postgres. The code simply works. I had set the extensions to "abc1 def abc !def" and after reading back got ["abc", "def"].

Comment: Similar works for me on Rails ~> 3 / Ruby ~> 2 / MySQL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key to understanding what's happening is knowing **when serialization occurs**. By inspecting [serialization.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb) in activerecord you'll see that the serialization magic happens by overriding type_cast_attribute_for_write, which is called on write_attribute. That is, **on attribute assignment**. So when you do:

```
document_type.extensions = something
```

something gets serialized and written to the extensions attribute. That is way before the save takes place. In fact, you don't even have to call save on document_type to have the attribute serialized.

The best workaround I know is to override `extensions=` on DocumentType. Something like:

```
def extensions=(value)
  value = [*value.gsub(/[^a-z ]+/i, '').split(' ')].uniq
  write_attribute :extensions, value
end
```

Comment: +1, solid answer here. Overwriting the setter is definitely the way to go here.

Comment: Excellent answer/explanation!

Answer (score -1):

I believe this append because the value of `extensions` is serialized while the model is validated by Rails, and your `process_extensions` method is called later (before the model is saved) and does not act as expected

Try to use before_validate instead

`before_validate :process_extensions`